# TextBox combined with LinkLabel in Datagridview column

Tags: vb.net

I have a Datagridview cell with some text in. I'd like to make just 1 word of this text into a link that will open a website but keep the remaining words as normal.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do achieve, would be to extend the (default) [DataGridViewTextBoxCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx) class (create a new one, inherit this behaviour) with some properties, like the cursor changing, clicking leads to opening a link if it's on the surface the link is on, etc.